# Programmatically clearing contenteditable in iOS does not reset predictive text

Tags: ios, contenteditable

If I clear the text from a div element that has contenteditable set to true, without it being blurred in iOS the predictive text bar is not reset. Instead it keeps showing predictions from whatever the text was before being cleared.

Is there a fix or a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try reloadInputViews() on the text field.

Comment: I am talking about a <div> contenteditable. Programmatically clearing its text or adding text to or pasting text in it doesn't seem to update the predictive text bar accordingly.